# Cannot add models to scene in Alice 2.4.1: CapabilityNotSetException

Tags: alice

When trying to add a new model (`add objects -> click model -> add instance to world`), I get a message box telling me that `An unknown error has occured`. The entity gets added to the object tree ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwIDD.jpg)), but does not appear in the render window.

I'm using Alice for the first time on this computer. It worked fine on other computers in earlier versions on different PCs. I have searched the Alice forums for this particular issue, but no avail. **The problem does not occur in Alice 2.3.3.**

```
Alice version: 2.4.1
os.name: Windows XP
os.version: 5.1
os.arch: x86
java.vm.name: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
java.vm.version: 20.0-b11
user.dir: C:\Programme\Alice 2.4\Required

Error during simulation.
javax.media.j3d.CapabilityNotSetException: Appearance: no capability to set transparencyAttributes
    at javax.media.j3d.Appearance.setTransparencyAttributes(Appearance.java:374)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.scenegraph.renderer.java3drenderer.AppearanceProxy.changed(AppearanceProxy.java:122)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.scenegraph.renderer.AbstractProxyRenderer.dispatchPropertyChange(AbstractProxyRenderer.java:38)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.scenegraph.renderer.AbstractRenderer.changed(AbstractRenderer.java:220)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.scenegraph.Element.onPropertyChange(Element.java:155)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.scenegraph.Element.onPropertyChange(Element.java:162)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.scenegraph.Appearance.setOpacity(Appearance.java:115)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.Model.propertyChanged(Model.java:201)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.Element.propertyChanged(Element.java:269)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.Property.onChanged(Property.java:427)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.Property.onSet(Property.java:453)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.Property.set(Property.java:470)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.Property.setHowMuch(Property.java:476)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.Property.set(Property.java:492)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.response.PropertyAnimation$RuntimePropertyAnimation.set(PropertyAnimation.java:90)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.response.PropertyAnimation$RuntimePropertyAnimation.update(PropertyAnimation.java:135)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.response.DoTogether$RuntimeDoTogether.update(DoTogether.java:71)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.response.DoInOrder$RuntimeDoInOrder.childUpdate(DoInOrder.java:58)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.response.DoInOrder$RuntimeDoInOrder.update(DoInOrder.java:101)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.response.DoTogether$RuntimeDoTogether.update(DoTogether.java:71)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.response.DoInOrder$RuntimeDoInOrder.childUpdate(DoInOrder.java:58)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.response.DoInOrder$RuntimeDoInOrder.update(DoInOrder.java:101)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.util.OneShot.scheduled(OneShot.java:56)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.Scheduler.schedule(Scheduler.java:72)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.core.Scheduler.run(Scheduler.java:98)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.authoringtool.util.DefaultScheduler.simulateOnce(DefaultScheduler.java:117)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.alice.authoringtool.util.DefaultScheduler.run(DefaultScheduler.java:78)
    at edu.cmu.cs.stage3.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.run(AbstractScheduler.java:45)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

[image: see screenshot]